# Join / merge / combine a DWG / DXF files into single DWG / DXF file in such way that it will fit into a steel plate

Tags: node.js, dxf, dwg, cnc

Generally the goal is to get a pre-processed file that can be used to import into a cnc plasma cutter to get the time needed for evaluation.

So we ned to join / merge / combine a DWG / DXF files into single DWG / DXF file in such way that it will fit into a steel plate. Additionally elements on the drawings should have a minimum space in between.

Can this be done in JS? JAVA? can't find any lib which can do this already?

Comment: You need a JS code? or the other way - external application is good solution for You?

Answer (score 1):

[Deepnest.io](https://deepnest.io/) is an open source app for arranging parts for CNC/Laser/Plasma cutting. You can specify space between parts, rotation, part in part, ...

Comment: Thanks for this feedback, did you tried to used it as an API service?

Comment: I have not used it as an API service.